# Remote Config Callback not received - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Guys i am tired with this, I have tried this things in demo project there it's working proper and can able to fetch remote config values.

But in my project when i am integrating Remote config setup i am not getting callback of fetch method.

Here is code what I have done.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()

    let settings = RemoteConfigSettings()
    settings.minimumFetchInterval = 0
    remoteConfig.configSettings = settings

    remoteConfig.setDefaults(fromPlist: "RemoteConfigDefaults")
    self.getRemoteConfig()
}
func getRemoteConfig() {

    print(remoteConfig["colorPrimaryDark"].stringValue ?? "NOT FOUND")

    remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: TimeInterval(10)) { (status, error) in

        if status == .success {
            print("Config fetched!")
            self.remoteConfig.activate(completionHandler: { (error) in
              // ...
            })
        }
        else {
            print("Config not fetched")
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error available.")")
        }
        self.PrintConfigValues()
    }

}

func PrintConfigValues() {
    print("REMOTE VALUES : ----- \(remoteConfig["colorPrimaryDark"].stringValue ?? "NOT FOUND")")
}
```

What would be the possibilities why i am not getting callback of fetch method. Please help me out.

Comment: Are you sure about setting the whole thing properly? You may miss something with the integration.

Comment: I have added all things, here is my pod file: 
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'

Only one thing is different that i have multiple projects inside my main project. But when i am enabling log of firebase, it don't give me error of remote config if any.

Comment: The only thing that is probably different between the demo and real project is the config (I'm assuming), I would double check the config is correct and your app's Firebase framework is initialised properly. Also are you getting any console output related to RemoteConfig?

Comment: @kd02
Firebase initialised properly, as i am getting log of firebase analytics started. Also i am getting log of remote config. Last log what i have got from remote config and firebase analytics are 

"2020-02-26 14:47:22.027066+0530 POP[8674:2482435] 6.15.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60201000 started "  


"[Firebase/RemoteConfig][I-RCN000067] Successfully set configSettings. Developer Mode: false, Minimum Fetch Interval:0.000000, Fetch timeout:60.000000 "

Comment: @JaimishShah seems like everything is working then, only thing I can think of is try profile the network request (using Network instrument or Charles) and see what is happening to the request.

Comment: how we do that @kd

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you saying that the code within .fetch is not running at all? Did you check to see if the error var was set, and if so, print out the error? What does your .plist file * RemoteConfigDefaults* look like? Also, are you authenticated when running this code?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have implemented this line in your **Appdelegate** file:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FIRApp.configure()

    return true
}
```

Comment: yes i have already implemented in appdelegate 

FirebaseApp.configure()